# How to access shared drive connected to Airport Extreme router?

Tags: networking, file-sharing

I have an external hard drive connected to my Airport Extreme. I keep my photo and music files on it and can access them from both a Mac and a Windows XP machine.

For some reason I can't find, much less connect to, it on my Ubuntu 10.10 machine. I can see my router in the "network" folder but can't seem to find and connect to the shared drive.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am somewhat of a novice with Ubuntu and networking.

Thanks

Comment: This question is abandoned - if you feel this is in error, then please flag explaining why and the moderators will re-open it.

Comment: This question makes sense, I am a linux user and cannot connect to airport extreme attached hdd. Please reopen it.

Comment: @KajalSinha - the user is long gone.  Please create your own question which you can maintain yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure it has something to do with permissions. For me, the solution was to open AirPort Utility on my Mac, go to Disks->File Sharing, and set "AirPort Disks Guest Access" to "Read and write". Once I did that, the drives connected to my AirPort Extreme showed up in the Network browser from Ubuntu.